# keep listening broadcast receiver on all activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

After knowing android 8+ doesn't support broadcastreceivers that register in the manifest file.
I want to know if there is any way to register the broadcast reveiver on all activities without doing it separately on each activity?

Comment: You can register your receiver in one activity and extend all activities to that activity. Will this not work?

Comment: I just called the broadcast on each activity separately.  on each activity onResume with register and onPause with unregister.

Comment: You can add that in one activity some thing like base activity and then extend all activities to base activity.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can think about - is a [ActivityLifececleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks). This is sort of subscription to all activities in your application.
So you have to implement next steps:

1. To add your custom Application class (and mention it in your manifest).
2. To implement interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in your custom Application class.
3. To implement needed callback method(s). You can use "onActivityCreated" in your case and put your "for-all-activities"-code inside it.

Comment: please share any code for this issue